# AngularJS: forward to login page for authentication, retain route as GET parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm a bit of an Angular newbie. I'm trying to write an Angular service that on any page, will check if a user is logged in, and if not, forward them to a login page, **passing their current path as a a GET parameter**.

I'm almost there, but it's not quite working. The problem I'm having is as follows: if the user goes to `#/articles/my-articles/`, they get forwarded to `#/login/?next=%2Farticles%2F:module%2F`.

In other words, it looks as though Angular is passing the route pattern, not the actual URL.

This is my authentication code:

```
auth.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$user', 'TOKEN_AUTH', 'PROJECT_SETTINGS', function ($rootScope, $location, $user, TOKEN_AUTH, PROJECT_SETTINGS) {
    var MODULE_SETTINGS = angular.extend({}, TOKEN_AUTH, PROJECT_SETTINGS.TOKEN_AUTH);
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (e, next, current) {
        if (next.$$route && !next.$$route.anonymous && !$user.authenticated) {
          var nextParam = next.$$route.originalPath;
          $location.url(MODULE_SETTINGS.LOGIN + '?next=' + nextParam);
        }
    });
}]);
```

I can get the original path in a hacky way using `current.params.module` - but that doesn't help me, because it seems that `routeChangeStart` is fired several times and the `current` object is undefined on all but the last fire.

This is my routes file:

```
articles.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/articles/:module/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/article_list.html',
        controller: 'ArticlesListCtrl'
    })
    .when('/articles/:module/:id/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/articles/article_detail.html',
        controller: 'ArticlesDetailCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The basic problem is that the first time `routeChangeStart` fires, the `current` object is undefined. Only on the third time it fires is `current.params` available, and by that point `next.$$route.anonymous` has been set to true, so it is too late to forward to the correct URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auth.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$user', 'TOKEN_AUTH', 'PROJECT_SETTINGS', function ($rootScope, $location, $user, TOKEN_AUTH, PROJECT_SETTINGS) {
    var MODULE_SETTINGS = angular.extend({}, TOKEN_AUTH, PROJECT_SETTINGS.TOKEN_AUTH);
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (e, next, current) {
        if (!$user.authenticated) {
          $location.url(MODULE_SETTINGS.LOGIN + '?next=' + $location.path());
          $location.replace();
        }
    });
}]);
```

If logging in is not a AngularJS view, you may have to provide an `otherwise` route:
(depends on your $locationProvider config)

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({
    template: 'Redirecting…',
    controller : 'Redirect'
});

...

articles.controller('Redirect', ['$location', function($location) {
    if (someConditionThatChecksIfUrlIsPartOfApp) {
        location.href = $location.path();
        return;
    } else {
        // Show 404
    }
}]);
```

Side note: you shouldn't read `$$`-prefixed properties, they are private AngularJS variables.
Also note: don't use `$` prefixes (`$user`) in your own code, these are public properties, reserved for AngularJS.

Comment: Instant perfect fix, thank you so much :) Thanks also for the general Angular advice, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My solution works on Angular 1.2.13 :
preventDefault stops angular routing and $window.location sends me out to login page. This is working on a ASP.NET MVC + Angular app.

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $window.location = '/Login';
            }        
    });
```